# How to refresh/update Model content without reloading the view on submit button without partial view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Below the view you can see I used a table and loaded content from the model.
like Static table.
The thing is I want to refresh model content that is valued without reloading the view.
Is it possible to perform this without using a partial view? **
View

```
    @model SampleWebApp.Models.SampModel;          ---Model

    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                <button id="btnRefreshLevels" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Refresh</button>                                                             --Submit button
    </div>
      
      <table class="table table-primary table-bordered mb-0">
        <thead class="thead-primary">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center">#</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">Level 1</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">Level 2</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">Level 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Level 1</th>
                @if (Model.Level1a == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px;" /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width:50px; height:auto;" /></td>
                }
                @if (Model.Level1b == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px; " /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width:50px; height:auto;" /></td>
                }
                @if (Model.Level1c == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px; " /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width:50px; height:auto;" /></td>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Level 2</th>
                @if (Model.Level2a == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px;" /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width:50px; height:auto;" /></td>
                }
                @if (Model.Level2b == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px;" /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width:50px; height:auto;" /></td>
                }
                @if (Model.Level3b == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px; " /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width:50px; height:auto;" /></td>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Level 3</th>
                @if (Model.Level3a == false)
                {
                    @*<td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width:40px; height:auto;" /></td>*@
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px;" /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width: 50px; height: auto;" /></td>
                }
                @if (Model.Level3b == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px; " /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width: 50px; height: auto;" /></td>
                }
                @if (Model.Level3c == false)
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/cross_tick.png" style="width: 40px; height: 41.8px; " /></td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td style="text-align:center"><img src="~/img/accept_tick.png" style="width:50px; height:auto;" /></td>
                }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The thing is I want to refresh model content that is valued without reloading the view.
Is it possible to perform this without using a partial view? **

Comment: First of all could you please share details of your `SampModel`. In addition, what do you want to update? How do you expecting to update it without reloading it? For example, How do you decide when to update it, onlick or on load or what? Please share your  expectations. Based on your requirement It can be implemented using `Ajax`.

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution? Is there anything else that I can assist you on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to perform this without using partial view?

Though partial view would be an ideal use here however, as you are looking around without using partial view so yes in that case you could use `Ajax` which will call a `URL` for your model `content/value` from your controller then bind the value in your table without reloading the whole page.

You could follow below steps to implement that.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
    <button id="btnRefreshLevels" class="btn btn-danger">Refresh</button>
</div>

<table class="table table-primary table-bordered mb-0" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <thead class="thead-primary">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">#</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Level 1</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Level 2</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Level 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bindTableDataWithoutReloading">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
@section scripts {
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnRefreshLevels").click(function(e) {
               $('#bindTableDataWithoutReloading').empty();
           // alert("Clicked!");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:5094/Member/RandomMemberList",
                success: function(response) {

                    $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                        $('#bindTableDataWithoutReloading').append(
                            '<tr>'+
                            '<td>' + value.name + '</td>'+
                            '<td>' + value.category +'</td>'+
                            '<td>' + value.description + '</td>'+
                            '<td><img src="/images/'+ value.photoUrl +'"  height="50" width="75" /></td>'+
                            '</tr>'
                            );
                    })

                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

        });



    });
</script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult RandomMemberList()
        {
            var members = _context.Members.ToList();
            var rnd = new Random();
            var randomized = members.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next());

            List<Member> newRandomList = new List<Member>();

            foreach (var value in randomized)
            {
                newRandomList.Add(value);
            }
            return Ok(newRandomList);
        }
```

**Model:**

```
public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Category { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        
    }
```

***Note:***

In my sample, I am calling a `controller` which will return a `random list` when the `refresh button clicked`.

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

There are two part in this sample one is `textbox` input and another is `table`. As you can see when you would click on `Refresh Button` it will load the list with each time random order without reloading the full page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a try by using JavaScript .